# $\mathrm{Aut}(D_4)$ is isomorphic to $D_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

> *Problem statement*: I need to find out if $\mathrm{Aut}(D_4)$ is isomorphic to $D_4$ and explain my answer. I already know that it **is** isomorphic, so now all I need to do is to prove it.

I assume that first we need to look where it sends $s$ and $t$ and it must send them to elements that satisfy the same relations()
And then need to show that those two are conjugation by some element in $D_4$(?)

Any help is appreciated.
I was hoping for a duplicate post, but couldn't find it.

Thank you!

Comment: It is (almost) answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698913/order-of-automorphism-group) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975818/automorphisms-in-the-dihedral-groups).

Comment: There is even a [video lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-VlZK2GLJg) giving the proof on the whiteboard.

Comment: video at 19:05;
for n = 3,4,6, we have $D_6$,$D_8$,$D_12$, not $D_4$ . am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, his notation is $D_{2n}$ instead of $D_n$. So $D_8$ has $8$ elements, and is your $D_4$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shortest proof I can think of:

Since an automorphism sends a generator to a generator, and is completely determined by its image on generators, we have, at most, $10$ automorphisms $\phi \in \text{Aut}(D_4)$ since we have $2$ choices for $\phi(r)$, and $5$ choices for $\phi(s)$ (automorphisms are *order-preserving*).

However, since $\text{Inn}(D_4) \leq \text{Aut}(D_4)$ has order $4$ (being isomorphic to $D_4/Z(D_4)$), we see that $|\text{Aut}(D_4)| = 4$, or $8$.

Define $\rho: D_4 \to D_4$, by $\rho(r) = r, \rho(s) = sr$. Then $\rho$ is outer, as all inner automorphisms have order $2$, and $\rho$ has order $4$. One should prove that $\rho$ is indeed an automorphism (surjectivity is the main concern), but I will omit this (it should not be hard to see $\{r,rs\}$ generate $D_4$). Thus $\text{Aut}(D_4)$ has order $8$.

Let $\sigma$ be the inner automorphism induced by $s$. Note $\rho^2(r) = r$, while $\sigma(r) = r^3$, so $\langle \rho\rangle \cap \langle \sigma\rangle = 1_{D_4}$. Thus $\langle\rho\rangle\langle \sigma\rangle = \text{Aut}(D_4)$, so that $\text{Aut}(D_4) = \langle \rho,\sigma\rangle$.

Finally, note that $\rho\sigma(r) = \rho(r) = r =  \sigma(r^3) = \sigma\rho^3(r)$ and:

$\rho\sigma(s) = \rho(s) = sr = \sigma(sr^3) = \sigma\rho^3(s)$, so that $\rho\sigma = \sigma\rho^3$, and:

$r \mapsto \rho, s \mapsto \sigma$ is the desired isomomorphism $D_4 \to \text{Aut}(D_4)$.

---

Note the two maps (of the possible $10$ above) which fail to yield automorphisms are those that send $s \mapsto r^2$, because they are not surjective.

Comment: Perhaps the first part can be shortened -- using $Aut(C_4)$ we see that $Aut(D_4)$ has order $4\cdot \phi(4)=8$.

Comment: I compute $\rho^2(s)=\rho(s)\rho(r)=sr^4=s$ and $\rho^2(r)=\rho(r)^3=r^9=r$, so it would seem that your $\rho$ has order $2$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen oops! I used the wrong value for $\rho(r)$, I will fix this.

Comment: Excuse me, but why do we have 5 choices for $\phi (s)$?  I see that the fifth is $\phi(s)=r^2$, but I don't see why that qualifies as an option.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you already know that the automorphism group of the $8$-element dihedral group $D_4$ contains $8$ elements. Here is how you can argue that it is actually isomorphic (though not canonically) to $D_4$ itself.

Given a square in the plane, its $4$ corners are also (alternatingly chosen) vertices of a unique octagon. That octagon has $4$ more vertices that also form a square; call the corners of the original square black vertices, and the remaining one white corners. The symmetry group of the octagon is a $16$-element group $D_8$. It contains your original $D_4$ as colour-preserving subgroup; it has index$~2$ and is therefore a normal subgroup. Conjugation defines a natural group morphism from $D_8$ to $\operatorname{Aut}(D_4)$. The kernel of this morphism contains the $2$-element centre $Z$ of $D_8$, and it is easy to see that it is actually equal to it: no non-central element of $D_8$ commutes with all elements of the subgroup $D_4$. So you get an injective group morphism $D_8/Z\to\operatorname{Aut}(D_4)$. Since you know that both groups have $8$ elements, this is in fact an isomorphism.

Then it remains to show that $D_8/Z\cong D_4$. For this it suffices to choose a similar presentation for $D_8$ and $D_4$ (either two adjacent reflections or a generating rotation and a reflection will do), map the generators of $D_8$ to corresponding generators of $D_4$, and check that the nontrivial element of $Z$ is mapped to the identity of $D_4$ (again using equal sizes and the fact that the morphism is clearly surjective suffice).

Answer (score 2):

Let $D_8\cong H\leq D_{16}=G$,
where
$$D_{16}=\{1, a, a^2, a^3, a^4, a^5, a^6, a^7, b, ba, ba^2, ba^3, ba^4, ba^5, ba^6, ba^7\}$$
and
$$H=\{1, a^2, a^4, a^6, b, ba^2, ba^4, ba^6\}.$$
Let $G$ act on $H$ by conjugation.
That is,
$g\cdot h=ghg^{-1}$.
Since $H$ is normal in $G$,
this action is well-defined.

Consider the permutation representation $\theta:G\to S_H$.
Recall that $\ker{\theta}=C_G(H)$.
In this case,
$\theta(g)$ is a group homomorphism on $H$,
the image of $\theta$ is contained in $\text{Aut }{H}$.
Then $$G/\ker{\theta}\cong \text{Im }{\theta}\leq \text{Aut }{H}.$$

It is easy to show that $\ker{\theta}=C_G(H)=Z(G)$.
Hence, $G/\ker{\theta}=G/Z(G)\cong D_8$.
Now we show that $\theta$ is onto.
Then $D_8\cong \text{Aut }{D_8}$ follows from the First Isomorphism Theorem.

For any $\varphi\in \text{Aut }{H}$,
we want to find $g\in G$ such that $\theta(g)=\varphi$.
Note that $a^2$ and $b$ are independent generator of $H$.
$\varphi$ is completely determined by $\varphi(a^2)$ and $\varphi(b)$.
Since $\varphi$ is an automorphism,
it preserve the order of the element.
Thus, $|\varphi(a^2)|=|a^2|=4$
and $|\varphi(b)|=|b|=2$.
Comparing the order,
we have $\varphi(a^2)\in \{a^2, a^6\}$ and $\varphi(b)\in \{b, ba^2, ba^4, ba^6\}$.
($\varphi(b)\neq a^4$, otherwise, $\theta$ is not onto.)
We have the following $8$ possibilities.

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\varphi(a^2)=a^2 \\
\varphi(b)=b
\end{array}\right.
\Rightarrow \varphi=\theta(a^4)|_{H} \text{ or }\theta(a^8)|_{H}
~~,~~
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\varphi(a^2)=a^6 \\
\varphi(b)=b
\end{array}\right.
\Rightarrow \varphi=\theta(ba^4)|_{H} \text{ or }\theta(b)|_{H}
$$
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\varphi(a^2)=a^2 \\
\varphi(b)=ba^2
\end{array}\right.
\Rightarrow \varphi=\theta(a^3)|_{H} \text{ or }\theta(a^7)|_{H}
~~,~~
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\varphi(a^2)=a^6 \\
\varphi(b)=ba^2
\end{array}\right.
\Rightarrow \varphi=\theta(ba^5)|_{H} \text{ or }\theta(ba)|_{H}
$$
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\varphi(a^2)=a^2 \\
\varphi(b)=ba^4
\end{array}\right.
\Rightarrow \varphi=\theta(a^2)|_{H} \text{ or }\theta(a^6)|_{H}
~~,~~
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\varphi(a^2)=a^6 \\
\varphi(b)=ba^4
\end{array}\right.
\Rightarrow \varphi=\theta(ba^6)|_{H} \text{ or }\theta(ba^2)|_{H}
$$
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\varphi(a^2)=a^2 \\
\varphi(b)=ba^6
\end{array}\right.
\Rightarrow \varphi=\theta(a)|_{H} \text{ or }\theta(a^5)|_{H}
~~,~~
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\varphi(a^2)=a^6 \\
\varphi(b)=ba^6
\end{array}\right.
\Rightarrow \varphi=\theta(ba^7)|_{H} \text{ or }\theta(ba^3)|_{H}
$$
Therefore, $\theta$ is onto. (For any $\varphi\in \text{Aut }{H}$,
if $\varphi(a^2)=a^{2+4i}$ and $\varphi(b)=ba^{2j}\in G=D_{16}$, where $i\in \{0,1\}$ and $j\in \{0,1,2,3\}$,
then choose $g=a^{4-j}b^i$.
We have $\theta(g)=\varphi$.)

Comment: Why is $G/Z(G)$ isomorphic to $D_8$?

Comment: @jsmith You can check that $D_{16}/Z=\langle aZ, bZ: |aZ|=4, |bZ|=2, aZbZaZ=bZ\rangle=\{Z, aZ, a^2 Z, a^3 Z, bZ, baZ, ba^2 Z, ba^3 Z\}$. See Theorem 6.13 in Hungerford's _Algebra_.